# Is Mongo good for transient storage (high volume of object creates & deletes)?

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that will periodically create a large number (10,000+) of hashes (collections of name/value pairs).  The hashes may be manipulated a few times, and then deleted.

Is MongoDB an appropriate choice for this?  Are there any obviously-better-suited alternatives?

Comment: Is storing the hashes in memory an option? 10,000+ doesn't sound like a lot of name/value pairs to keep around in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo is a document database and a bit overkill for key/value pairs. It's strength lies in that it can do ad hoc queries in the documents. If you need this, then that's great.

Take a look at tokyocabinet. This is rumored to be a very fast key/value store.

Answer (score 1):

**@jmay**: there are tons of potential solutions for this stuff: Redis, TokyoCabinet, MongoDB, CouchDB, Cassandra, HBase... just take your pick.

If you consider 10,000+ to be "a large number" then any of these systems will work for you. I'm using Mongo with systems that have four more zeros.

Personally, I like Mongo because it's relatively quick and easy to set up. Check out their [quickstart guide](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart) and you'll see what I mean.